# Get images and text from WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF RichTextBox which contains some text and images. How would I extract all of this and save it anywhere?

Currently it works only by getting the text from the RichTextBox, but I need images as well. Here is the code where I extract strings from the RichTextBox:

```
private string getStringFromRTB(RichTextBox rtb) {
      TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
      return tr.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Use the `TextRange.Save()` and `TextRange.Load()` methods instead.